# I have a list of index to mark which position to insert to DataTable, how to iterate while insert without messing the position?

Tags: c#

I have a `List<Tuple<String, Index>>` that I need to insert to DataTable

```
A,5  
B,8
```

meaning I will insert A to position 5 in DataTable, B to position 8, etc.

how do you insert to DataTable in proper position because when you do something like

```
foreach list in lists
{
    //do something
    dt.Rows.InsertAt(dr, position); //insert to DataTable
}
```

it will mess the index because every iteration, the index will not be valid anymore. I tried `foreach list in lists.OrderByDescending` but in some cases, it will also break.

Here's one case where OrderByDescending will break position.

```
A  
B  
C  
F  
G
```

I have a list with `(D, 3)` and `(E, 4)`. Here's what happened if I OrderByDescending / Insert data in reverse order.

First Iteration will insert the E

```
A  
B  
C  
F  
E  //WRONG PLACE
G
```

Second Iteration will insert the D

```
A  
B  
C  
D  
F  
E  //WRONG PLACE
G
```

Comment: Can't you use the InsertAt method?

Comment: sorry I posted the wrong code. I did use InsertAt, please check my updated code.

Comment: Looks like you have to order your tuples by index and keep an offset variable initialized at 0, which you increment each time you insert a value and add to the index in your list (to compensate the previously inserted value offset).

Comment: @InBetween yep, your solution is indeed easier

Comment: The question would be, where do you get your indexes to insert at from. In your second example `E` is correctly inserted at the 5th position (as it is a 0 based index). To be inserted correctly, D and E should BOTH have index 3 when inserted in reverse order.

Comment: @Adwaenyth: Yes I'm aware both must have index 3 to be correctly inserted when reversed, but I have no control over the List I'm iterating.

Comment: The question remains, where do the respective index numbers come from. You need to understand how they are generated before you insert them into your table, otherwise you will never get it right... if you have absolutely no idea how those indexes are generated and no possibility to find out, you need to scrap them alltogether and determine the insert position yourself.

Comment: @Adwaenyth: The index number assume that it represent the position in the alphabet. So A would be 0, B would be 1, C would be 2, and the list goes on. Obviously this is made simple for the sake of complex discussion but I hope you get the general idea.

Comment: @Adwaenyth: Ok here's the better example. So imagine we have a `list` with "Apple, Orange, Banana" as value, some incompetent programmer wants to fill "Melon" and "Tomato" between "Orange" and "Banana". So he will make a list with following value ("Melon", 3), ("Tomato", 4) and expect the final result as Apple, Orange, Melon, Tomato, Banana

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first ensure that the list is sorted by the index **ascending**, for example:

```
lists.Sort((x1, x2) => x1.Item2.CompareTo(x2.Item2)); // omit this if the list is already sorted
```

Now, before you can move them to the correct postion, add the rows to the end of the `DataTable` with `Add`, for example with `List.ForEach`:

```
lists.ForEach(x => dt.Rows.Add(x.Item1)); // added to the end
```

Now they are at the end of the table in the correct order but at the wrong position.

```
int newRowsBeginAt = dt.Rows.Count - lists.Count; // where are they, at the end
```

Now you can iterate this list (in ascending index order) and move them to their position:

```
for (int i = 0; i < lists.Count; i++)
{
    int currentIndex = newRowsBeginAt + i;
    int newIndex = lists[i].Item2;
    if (currentIndex != newIndex)
    {
        DataRow row = dt.Rows[currentIndex];
        object[] data = row.ItemArray;  // need to clone it otherwise RemoveAt will delete data
        dt.Rows.RemoveAt(currentIndex); // remove it from the table
        row.ItemArray = data;           // needed to restore data
        dt.Rows.InsertAt(row, newIndex);// insert to correct position
    }
}
```

That works because you don't change the indexes of earlier moved rows later if you start with the lower-indexes and then move to the higher indexes.

---

Tested with your sample data:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Col");
dt.Rows.Add("A");
dt.Rows.Add("B");
dt.Rows.Add("C");
dt.Rows.Add("F");
dt.Rows.Add("G");


var lists = new List<Tuple<string, int>>()
{
    Tuple.Create("D", 3), Tuple.Create("E", 4)
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you reverse the list so that you add the ones at the end first, you should not get any issues using `InsertAt`.

So it appears that for the list coming in, the position values of each tuple is the "absolute" position, so-to-speak, of where that entry needs to go. If that is the case, sort the incoming tuple list by ascending position value, and then insert them in order.

The values already in the list that you are adding to appear not to matter as much, it's the incoming values that are important. With the sorted list to add, this should ensure everything ends up where they need to be.

Comment: please check my example, still having issue when using reversed list.

Comment: Based on the documentation for `InsertAt` for DataTable Rows, it looks like those are actually being inserted into the correct position. The position to insert at is 0 based, and for (E, 4) that puts it exactly where it was supposed to go.

Comment: Yes, but that's not what I want. Because when you order by asc, it actually inserted in a correct position which is A B C D E F G, but it will break when the list is reversed (like in the example). But both aren't the solution, because there are some cases where ASC is fine and DESC will break and vice versa and I have no control over the list im iterating, so is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: I guess the followup question would have to be, what is the index part of the tuple supposed to mean? With your descending order example, you would need to insert D first in order for E to go to the "right" place as you described. If you are simply alphabetizing, then why base off the index given in the tuple at all?

Comment: So imagine we have a `list` with "Apple, Orange, Banana" as value, some incompetent programmer wants to fill "Melon" and "Tomato" between "Orange" and "Banana". So he will make a list with following value ("Melon", 3), ("Tomato", 4) and expect the final result as Apple, Orange, Melon, Tomato, Banana